# Using Valgrind on an Embedded project

Tags: embedded, valgrind

Currently I am working on an Embedded Project. I am using IAR Embedded Workbench IDE and target platform is 8051-based microcontroller. Is it possible to use Valgrind tool to check the code I wrote?

Comment: Have you asked the valgrind users mailing list ? Have you checked http://valgrind.org/ ?

Comment: You should check this page, Valgrind Supported Platforms[1]. 8051 micro-controller instruction set is not supported.

  [1]: http://valgrind.org/info/platforms.html

Comment: @jclin Post your comment as the answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, and Yes*.

No: As another commenter said, Valgrind does not run on 8051 architectures, so you can't use Valgrind as you would on an x86 system.

Yes*: (the asterisk (*) is because it's a limited "yes")

But you can use Valgrind on the non-8051/IAR-specific parts of your code if you:

1. Separate the 8051-specific and IAR-specific code from the architecture/compiler agnostic code.

   - You'll probably want to do this so the code doesn't get any bigger as a result of separating the agnostic code. (I'm assuming code size is at a premium since you're working on an 8051.)
2. Compile the architecture/compiler agnostic code with gcc and run it using Valgrind on your desktop/laptop development machine, which is probably an x86 machine.

   - Of course you can use any other Valgrind-supported architecture/compiler, x86/gcc isn't your only choice.

This way Valgrind will be able to check some of your code, which is better than nothing.

And separating the compiler/chip specific parts of your code will also make it more portable and reusable.

Oh, and this isn't directly related, but you should also consider using a static analysis program like PC-Lint: http://www.gimpel.com/html/index.htm

It checks some things that Valgrind checks, and many things that Valgrind doesn't check. Plus it will check *all* of your code, not just the non-8051/IAR code.

There are plenty of similar tools out there; PC-Lint is the most popular that I've seen.

Comment: No exactly. Of course you can always check your code on other architecture for common errors, but some architecture dependent issues might not be found. For me, I caught a bug of endian. In Linux 32/64 bit, Valgrind does not have any issue. However, it is a issue on Sun SPARC.

Comment: That's what I meant by "This way Valgrind will be able to check some of your code, which is better than nothing." Since you're running on a different architecture no 8051-related architecture issues will be found.

Comment: I think you should know what 8051 is. It is a micro-controller, not a generic CPU. It won't have full featured OS and many operations are done by direct IO and hardware interrupts, and/or using very small RTOS. So most of the program wrote for 8051 could not be compiled and run on generic OS using GCC, so I think it is not possible to check 8051 memory issues under Valgrind.

Comment: You're correct, @jclin, but I'm not sure what you're getting at. No, the 8051-specific stuff won't be run or tested in Valgrind. But my answer was trying to say that Valgrind can at least run & test non-8051/IAR code if it is separated from the 8051/IAR code and then run on a system supported by Valgrind. Is my answer unclear or misleading? If so, can you please suggest improvements? Thanks!

Comment: You are right, too. You can compile and test the platform independent code in other platforms which runs Valgrind.

Answer (score 1):

You should check this page, Valgrind [Supported Platforms](http://valgrind.org/info/platforms.html). 8051 micro-controller instruction set is not supported by Valgrind.

Moreover, you should know Valgrind is an instruction simulator. It means you have to run Valgrind on the system, and it runs your code with OS and base layer of C or other POSIX libraries to simulate your program's memory read/write, or profiling. So 8051 is impossible to run Valgrind.